# Python: How to call a function with django?

Tags: python, django, function, web, terminal

I am new absolutely new to Django and have been stuck on this problem for some time now, for some reason they don't actually explicitly teach it in any tutorial I could find.

So what I want is to create a simple button I Django that calls a simple python function that prints "hello" to the terminal? I don't want to change view or anything, just to call the function

**EDIT:**

This is what i have so far, left side is my view.py and right side is the html file

[image]

Comment: You do that through a view: the browser can make HTTP requests that are then handled by a view. That is the only way to communicate with the webserver (except for sockets, etc. but that is not very relevant here).

Comment: Okay i see. But how would i go about creating that? I have updated my post @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="" name="mybtn">Download</button>
</form>

def index(request):
    print('***Loaded***')
    if (request.GET.get('mybtn')):
        print('**Just Clicked on BTN')
```

Comment: I tried running that, but the last line in your code never runs. And do i have to add it to my index func or can create another function?

Comment: Yes, the "IF" part you have to add it to your index func.

Comment: I have the exact code as shown in the answer, and then i added  `return render(request, "main/index.html") `

Comment: Does the function get triggered when you launch your template ? and what do you get in request when you hit the button ?

Comment: I think i figured out the mistake. For some reason your code workes if the value and name of the button is the same. Do they really have to be the same?

Comment: yes, the name will be passed on to the function.
If you re willing to give Django a go, I suggest you to follow this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgGIqRFvFFk&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK&ab_channel=thenewbosto

Answer (score 0):

In Django workflow is different, It follows model view template (MVT), So you have to define a function in view.py in which you will mention your HTML template file_name, then you have to bind that function with your web app's URL using urls.py file, so when ever that particular URL will hits, it call views function process your logic and return data in your HTML file.

view.py

```
def welcome(request):
    # here 'welcome.html' is your template it should be in templates directory 
    return render(request,'welcome.html')
```

urls.py

```
from myapp import views
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('home', views.welcome, name = 'welcome'),
]
```

I suggest you to read its official docs, or you can go through this [django crash course](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/04/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, this much I get, I'm just not sure how to connect the button to a function. I tried adding an `else-part` to the other answer provided. And for some reason only the else statement is run, the other part of the if-statement is never true